# Exec and sed commands

Tags: shell, sed, exec

The question is how to combine the following commands in one line and use exec.

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'echo "$(sed -n "\$p" "$1"),$1"' _ {} \;
```

The result: path and name of all .txt files.

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec sed -n '/stringA/,/stringB/p' {} \;
```

The result: lines between start and end parameters over all .txt files.

The requested result: give me lines between start and end parameters. The first line must be contain path and name of the .txt file.

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec ???? {} \;
```

> ./alpha/file01.txt
>
> stringA
>
> line1
>
> line2
>
> stringB
>
> ./beta/file02.txt
>
> stringA
>
> line1
>
> line2
>
> stringB

Thanks. 
T.

Comment: Were it me, I'd write a script that takes a list of file names (possibly empty) as arguments, and then does the processing for each argument: `for file in "$@"; do echo "$file"; sed -n '/StringA/,/StringB/p' "$file"; done` for example.  Place that in a file — `findit.sh`.  Then `find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh findit.sh {} +` does the rest.  If you need to make the `StringA` and `StringB` into arguments to `findit.sh`, so be it; require them as the first two arguments and adjust the script accordingly.  The only issue is the name `findit.sh` and removing it if you create it on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files are non-empty then all you need is:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec awk 'FNR==1{print FILENAME} /StringA/,/StringB/' {} +
```

If they can be empty then the simplest way to handle it is to use GNU awk for BEGINFILE:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec awk 'BEGINFILE{print FILENAME} /StringA/,/StringB/' {} +
```

Comment: Really simple solution. I tested other variant by SED but it was approximately two times slower than your AWK solution and little more difficult syntax. Thank you.
For example SED solution:
`find . -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'echo "$0" ; sed -n "/StringA/,/StringB/p" "$0"' {} \;`

Comment: You're welcome. sed is great for s/old/new on individual lines where old is a regexp and new is a backreference-enabled string. For anything else just use awk for simplicity, clarity, efficiency, portability, robustness, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to pipe the output of `find` to other commands than using `-exec`. Please try the following:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | while read -r -d "" f; do echo "$f"; sed -n "/stringA/,/stringB/p" "$f"; done
```

which yields:

```
./alpha/file01.txt
stringA
line1
line2
stringB
./beta/file02.txt
stringA
line1
line2
stringB
```

- `-print0` option in `find` merges the filenames delimited by a null character.
- `-d ""` option in `read` splits the input by a null character to properly reproduce the list of filenames.
- Then we can refer to `$f` as a filename in the `while` loop.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using *GNU* `sed` and `realpath`:

```
sed -sn '1F;/stringA/,/stringB/p' $(realpath *.txt)
```

Or, if relative paths are acceptable:

```
sed -sn '1F;/stringA/,/stringB/p' ./*.txt
```

If the code needs to recurse into subdirs:

```
sed -sn '1F;/stringA/,/stringB/p'  $(find . -name '*.txt')
```